# How to autorotate Custom Header Section View

Tags: uitableview, ios5, autorotate

I have a custom Section Header for my table. I have added a button to it
   button1.frame = CGRectMake(frame.size.width-70, 5.0, 35.0, 35.0);
This places the button in the top right hand corner. However when I autorotate into landscape, the button stays in same place as it was in portrait mode? What am I missing?

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame title:(NSString*)title section:(NSInteger)sectionNumber delegate:(id <SectionHeaderViewDelegate>)delegate AllAnswered:(SectionAnswered)sectionAnswered{

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

if (self != nil) {

    // Set up the tap gesture recognizer.
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleOpen:)];

    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    _delegate = delegate;
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


    //create applyAll image
    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(frame.size.width-70, 5.0, 35.0, 35.0);
    button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    button1.opaque = NO;
    button1.tag= 1;
    [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"carat-open.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(applyToAll:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:button1];
    _applyButton = button1;

     .............
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the button's `autoresizingMask`.

```
button1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```